# Kerning Editing of ttf file

Tags: fonts

I wanted to edit my font's ttf file and change the character interspacing whenever I write that font down in any software. I want to know if I can edit kerning or character interspacing of my ttf font file? Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have font editing software? If yes, what?

Comment: which font editing software can i use ?

Comment: There are a lot of editing packages. You'll need to research and determine that yourself based upon your system and it's capabilities. You might find https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ helpful